# Copy a row from a table to another with the same columns but different order in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

*Document*

Columns: `{DocumentColumns}`

*DocumentVersion*

Columns: `DocumentVersion_id(autoincrement)`, `{DocumentColumns}`

`{DocumentColumns}` are the same in both tables, but their order can differ.

I need that any change that happens in `Document`, must be added in `DocumentVersion`, so I created this trigger :

```
Create trigger copyDocumentVersionTrigger on dbo.Document after insert,update as 
insert into [DocumentVersion] select null as DocumentVersion_id,* from inserted
```

When I want to execute this request I get :

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure copyDocumentVersionTrigger, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
>       Operand type clash: bit is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Because the third column in `Document` is a bit, and the third one in `DocumentVersion` is a unique identifier ( and they are totally different columns, that only means that t-sql doesn't care about the named columns in the select, it only cares about the positions).

`{DocumentColumns}` can be changed dynamically after the creation of the trigger, so I can't just put explicitly the names.

Is there any simple solution to achieve this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64671/discussion-on-question-by-yeska-copy-a-row-from-a-table-to-another-with-the-same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently we don't consider it "simple" to obtain column names of the tables from sys.columns or from Information_Schema.Columns (which handily has a table name column), and then.... hmm, yes, if you construct a "dynamic SQL" statement to call with EXEC() then it won't have access to the [inserted] and [deleted], so you need to copy the row key column to a temporary table... I suppose that isn't simple.  Unless you are doing it one row at a time - then the row key column, is just one variable, and by calling sp_executesql with the appropriate parameter... hmm, again, today may be a headache day.

However... if that's a Microsoft SQL Server error message, then you can again use dynamic SQL to create view objects on one or both of the tables that simply have the column order changed - and you can write in your trigger (I think) if you want,

```
INSERT DocumentVersionView SELECT * FROM inserted;

INSERT DocumentVersionView SELECT dv.* FROM DocumentView dv JOIN inserted di ON blah blah blah
```

Whichever is required.  The INSERT will write to the table in the view.

Update: "Of course" DocumentVersionView doesn't have column DocumentVersion_id; the table column gets assigned automatically by your auto-increment.

Comment: I used dynamic sql, you can copy Inserted table in a temporary variable.